# Can't track down source of huge memory use

Tags: c++, memory-management

I've been trying to track down a memory problem for a couple of days - my program is using around 3GB of memory, when it should be using around 200MB-300MB. Valgrind is actually reporting that it is using ~300MB at its peak, and is not reporting any memory leaks.

The program reads an input file, and stores every unique word in that file. It is multi-threaded, and I've been running it using 4 threads. My major sources of data are:

- Constant-size array of wchar_t (4MB total)
- Map between words and a list of associated values. This grows with the size of input. If there are 1,000,000 unique words in the input file, there will be 1,000,000 entries in the tree.

I am doing a huge number of allocations and deallocations (using new and delete) -- at least two per unique word. Is it possible that memory I free is not being reused for some reason, causing the program to keep acquiring more and more memory? It consistently grabs more as it continues to run.

In general, any ideas about where I should go from here?

Edit 1 (based on advice from Graham):
One path I'll try is minimizing allocation. I'll work with a single string per thread (which may grow occasionally if a word is longer than this string is), but if I remember my code correctly this will eliminate a huge number of new/delete calls. If all goes well I'll be left with: one-time allocation of input buffer, one-time allocation of string-per-thread (with some reallocs), two allocs per map entry (one for key, one for value).

Thanks!

Comment: Graham's answer seems valid.  How are you determining how much memory is being used and what OS (and is it 64bit or 32bit) are you running?  Are the objects you're new-ing/deleting just data structures or full fledged class objects?

Comment: I'm using Valgrind and the command free -m (reports how much memory is free, gives me a rough idea when it uses a ton of memory). This is on 64-bit Linux. I've tried this using std::wstring and c-style strings.

Answer (score 7):

It's likely to be heap fragmentation. Because you are allocating and releasing small blocks in such huge quantities, it's probable that there are loads of small free chunks which are too small to be reused by subsequent allocations. Since these chunks are effectively wasted, the process has to keep grabbing more and more memory from the system to honour new allocations.

You may be able to mitigate the effect by first reserving a sufficiently large default capacity in each string with `string::reserve()`, and then clearing strings to empty when you're finished with them (rather than deleting). Then, keep a list of empty strings to be reused instead of allocating new ones all the time.

**EDIT:** the above suggestion assumes the objects being allocated are `std::string`s. If they're not, then you can probably still apply the general technique of keeping old empty objects around for reuse.

Comment: This sounds like the most likely issue at this point, thanks for the input! Edited my original post with a strategy I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

Memory your program frees should be returned to the heap where it can be allocated again.

However, that does not mean it is freed back to the operating system. Often, the app will continue to "own" memory that has been allocated and freed.

Is this a Windows app? How are you allocating and freeing the memory? And how are you determining how much memory the app is using?

Comment: If he is using Valgrind then it is linux.

Comment: Yeah it's built in Linux using gcc 4.4.4, I use new/delete, profiling with valgrind and free -m

Answer (score 0):

You should try wrapping the resource allocations into a class if you can.  Call new in the constructor, and delete in the destructor.  Try and take advantage of scope so memory management is done more automatically.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII